# Compatibility-breaking changes in High Sierra and iOS 11?

Tags: macos, compatibility, high-sierra, ios

I remember back in Yosemite and iOS 8, upgrading iCloud to use iCloud Drive would break iCloud's functionality on any devices running earlier OSes. Are there any features in macOS High Sierra and iOS 11 that would similarly break compatibility with earlier OSes?

I'm specifically wondering about features such as iMessage in iCloud, the HEIF file format for photos, and HEVC encoding for videos - these all seem like they would make irreversible changes to my data. Will devices not running High Sierra and iOS 11 still work with my iMessages, photos, and videos?

Comment: See if this answer helps:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287550/native-heif-support-in-macos-10-13-high-sierra/287552#287552