# iPhone 6 iOS 11 Public Beta: Camera format

Tags: iphone, ios

I've installed iOS 11 Public Beta on my iPhone 6 but it seems that I can't select the new **HEIF** format in `Settings -> Camera`.

How can I check if I'm taking picture in `JPG` or `HEIF`? Or is it an iPhone 7 and above exclusive feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardware **encode** for HEIF requires an **A10** chip, and thus is only supported on iPhone 7 and newer. This is why you don’t see the option to save as HEIF on your iPhone 6:

[image: HEIF Image Encode Support]

Hardware **decode** support starts with iPhone 6s and iPhone SE:

> For iOS, we have hardware decode on the minimum config of the A9 chip.

[image: HEIF Image Decode Support]

[Introducing HEIF and HEVC - WWDC 2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/503/)

However since all Apple devices will support at least **software decode**, you will be able to share HEIF images natively (by iMessage, or any other sharing service that negotiates decode capabilities) with all Apple devices.